# Preg match to validate only numbers integer or decimals with sign + or -

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Preg match to validate only whole numbers or decimals with sign + or -

How can I create a preg_match that only accepts decimal numbers which can have (or have no) + or - just when the number starts?

I put the following examples:

5 **true**

4.4 **true**

+5 **true**

+4.4 **true**

-5 **true**

-4.4 **true**

---

4.4- **false**

4.4+ **false**

44. **false**

For now I have a preg_match function that allows me to achieve this, but the problem is that I can enter the signs (. + -) in any part of the number, and I just need the signs (+ -) to be at the beginning and the point  if it is decimal.

```
preg_match('/^[0-9.+]+$/', $value)
```

Thanks friends.

Comment: You may use: `/^[+-]?\d*\.?\d+$/` or see this: https://regex101.com/r/jkaSiN/1

Comment: @anubhava It was just what I needed. Thank you for your help friend. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer.

You may use this regex for making `+` or `-` optional at the start.

```
^[+-]?\d*\.?\d+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jkaSiN/1)

**Regex Explanation:**

- `^`: Start
- `[+-]?`: Match optional `+` or `-`
- `\d*\.?\d+`: Match an integer or decimal number
- `$`: End